# Cannot convert value of type 'CFString' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Void>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<()>')

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, core-text, quartz-core

I am getting a build error, when I define the line

```
 let runFont : CTFontRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), kCTFontAttributeName)
```

And the error is:   Cannot convert value of type 'CFString' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer' (aka 'UnsafePointer<()>')

Comment: An `UnsafePointer` error usually means that the affected parameter is used as an inout pointer. Read the documentation by QuickHelp,  ⌥-click or ⌘-click on the symbol or pressing ⇧⌘0 and typing the method name.

Comment: Hi @vadian can you please give me a code example of how to solve it.. i have looked at the documentation and tries many ways but doesnt work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
let runFont = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), unsafeBitCast(kCTFontAttributeName, UnsafePointer<Void>.self)), CTFontRef.self)
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 version of @vadian answer:

```
let runFont = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), unsafeBitCast(kCTFontAttributeName, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self)), to: CTFont.self)
```